# Snakemake grouping output

Tags: snakemake

I have a fairly complex requirement for the `output` of one of my rules.
I have samples in a CSV file (`samples.csv`) with nested information like so:

```
region,run_id,sample_id
A,1,150
A,3,111
A,3,145
A,3,153
B,4,105
B,4,107
```

I have them stored in my `Snakefile` as a pandas dataframe.

```
samples = pd.read_csv("samples.csv").set_index(
    ["region", "run_id", "sample_id"], drop=False
)
```

I have a rule `demultiplex`, which takes in a fastq file that is a combination of all the `sample_id` reads for a `run_id` in a `region`

```
rule demultiplex:
    input:
        "analysis/{region}/{run}/basecalled.fastq"
```

What this demultiplex rule does is take in this combined fastq file and returns a fastq file for each `sample_id` (barcode) within that `run_id`.

So where I am struggling here is how to get the `output` to map to the `input`.

What I effectively want in the running example is the `demultiplex` rule to execute once for every valid (`region`, `run_id`) pair, but produce multiple files. So the desired groupings would be something like this:

```
input:
    "analysis/A/1/basecalled.fastq"
output:
    ["analysis/A/1/demultiplex/150.fastq"]

input:
    "analysis/A/3/basecalled.fastq"
output:
    ["analysis/A/3/demultiplex/111.fastq", 
     "analysis/A/3/demultiplex/145.fastq", 
     "analysis/A/3/demultiplex/153.fastq"]

input:
    "analysis/B/4/basecalled.fastq"
output:
    ["analysis/B/4/demultiplex/105.fastq", 
     "analysis/B/4/demultiplex/107.fastq"]
```

So the rule `demultiplex` in this example would run 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to touch a file for each fastq file that needs to be demultiplexed. In the code below the assumption is that the path to the master fastq files can be reconstructed from the information in the sample sheet (which should be the case if I understand correctly):

```
import pandas as pd

samples = pd.read_csv("samples.csv").set_index(
    ["region", "run_id", "sample_id"], drop=False
)

fastq= samples[['region', 'run_id']].drop_duplicates()

rule all:
    input:
        expand('analysis/{region}/{run}/demultiplex/demux.done', zip, \
            region= list(fastq['region']), run= list(fastq['run_id']))

rule demultiplex:
    input:
        "analysis/{region}/{run}/basecalled.fastq",
    output:
        touch('analysis/{region}/{run}/demultiplex/demux.done'),
    shell:
        r"""    
        demux {input} 
        """
```

Comment: This is effectively what I am doing at the moment as a work-around. I was hoping to find a solution where the `{sample_id}` could be inferred and the samples grouped by run and region without me having to do a lot of manual work like I am at the moment.  
Thank you though!